# Determine local extrema of 2 functions

Tags: calculus, functions

So I have 2 functions, $f(x)=cos(\frac{2}{x})$ and $g(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$

For f(x), how many local extrema it has? It is very weird because near 0 it is many up and down. So do they belong to local maximum and minimum?

For g(x) in the interval (-3,2). does it have any local extrema? Because in this interval there is global maximum at g(2) and global minimum at g(-3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ has infinitely many local maxima and infinitely many local minima as you have observed.

$g$ is strictly increasing in the given interval so it has no local maximum of minimum at any point of the open interval $(-3,2)$.